# How to extract words from text file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have been learning and stack one problem. I try to make searching specific name and employee number from text file. I tried to research the online around, but I did not find specifically much result.

How can I fix this :

> .\txtFileReader.java:15: error: cannot find symbol while((line =
>   filescan.readLine()) != null) ^ symbol: method readLine() location:
>   variable filescan of type Scanner 1 error

**Here is my code**:

```
File oldFile = new File("C:\\Tesseract-OCR\\" + name + ".txt");
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFile)))
{
    StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
    String text;
    while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        contents.append(text).append(lineSeparator);
        System.out.println(text);
        if (text.contains("*Department: @INFO. TECH"))
        {
            int index = text.indexOf("TECH");
            text = text.substring(index, text.length());
            System.out.println("Result :" + text);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my Tesseract OCR converted text file :**

> ATTENDANCE SHEET
>
> *Department: @INFO. TECH *Date: @18/08/2017
>
> *Year: @THIRD *Division: @C
>
> *Subject Code: @TBGOZ
>
> *Teacher Code: @ITIOOZO
>
> @IT001 @ITOOZ @IT003 @ITOO4
>
> m5 @IT006 @IT007 @IT008
>
> @IT009 @5910 m wm-
>
> m3 @IT014 m @IT016
>
> @IT017 @IT018 m @9219
>
> @IT021 mz @593 @IT024
>
> m @IT026 @IT027 @IT028
>
> @IT029 @m @IT031 W
>
> @IT033 m4 @lT035 @IT036

**I want to print output on console as:**

```
Department: INFO. TECH
Year: THIRD
Division: C
Subject Code: @TBGOZ
Teacher Code:ITIOOZO
```

Please tell me solution for above question.

Comment: There a thousands of examples on how to read text from a file using java as it is a very common (and beginner) task.  Have you tried looking?

Comment: I've just tested your code and it works. What is your question? The only thing I added was Exception handling.

Comment: I  pasted the code before you edited it. Where did " filescan" come from? I was using reader in the code, not  filescan.

Comment: I want to extract the particular words from text file like Department: INFO. TECH, Year: THIRD ,Division: C

Comment: Why did you put in the error for filescan? The code doesn't have it.

Comment: Yesss...!!Thanks @oldercoder Thanks a lot. Got what am expecting            Now output is Department: INFO. TECH 
Year: THIRD 
Division: C
Subject Code: TBGOZ 
Teacher Code: ITIOOZO

Comment: @AnupSonkusare can you check the answer approved??

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       File oldFile = new File("C:\\temp\\test2.txt");
       try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(oldFile))) {
           StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
           String text;
           String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
           while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null)
           {
               contents.append(text).append(lineSeparator);
              // System.out.println(text);
               String[] parsed = text.split("\\*");
               for (String p : parsed) {
                   if (!p.contains("Subject Code"))
                       p = p.replace("@", "");
                   if (p.startsWith("Department")) {
                       System.out.println(p);
                   } else if (p.startsWith("Year")) {
                       System.out.println(p);
                   } else if (p.startsWith("Division")) {
                       System.out.println(p);
                   } else if (p.startsWith("Subject Code")) {
                       System.out.println(p);
                   } else if (p.startsWith("Teacher Code")) {
                       System.out.println(p);
                   }                       


               }
           }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 

 }
```

Comment: How to do if I only want INFO. TECH,THIRD,C,@TBGOZ,ITIOOZO

Comment: Hey..Got the answer by               System.out.println(p.substring(p.lastIndexOf(" : ") + 1));